# Send body for a post json in Blackberry java OS6+

Tags: json, rest, blackberry, java-me

I need to send a body for a `POST` JSON to a REST service for Blackberry java OS6+. I have seen examples, but not how to create such a body.  Then, I need to send the body created earlier in a `POST`?
An example of the body that I need to send is this:

Body:

```json
{
  "name" : "my name",
  "password" : "asdf",
  "email" : "mail@mail.com",
  "gender" : 0,
}
```

And the service will return:

```json
{
   "response": {
     "status": "ok"
   }
}
```

Comment: Create a JSON object for request, use the data returned by toString() method of the request JSON object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THIS IS THE SOLUTION

Only had to change the String to JSONObject body.

Solamente tenia que cambiar el cuerpo String a JSONObject.

```
String url = "http://example.json";
String result;
String tipoConexion = Autenticacion.getConnectionString();
public Consumo4()
{        
     try{

         JSONObject json =  new  JSONObject ( 
                "{"+
                    "'name' : 'test',"+
                    "'email' : 'test@test.com',"+
                    "'password' : 'password',"+                     
                    "'gender' : 0,"+                        
                "}" 
                );
        HttpConnection connection = (HttpConnection)Connector.open(url+tipoConexion);
        connection.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.POST);

        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(json.length()));


         System.out.println("JSON A ENVIAR --> " + json);
         String size = "" + json.length();

         OutputStream os = connection.openOutputStream();
         os.write(json.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));

         ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
         InputStream responseData = connection.openInputStream();
         byte[] buffer = new byte[20000];
         int bytesRead = responseData.read(buffer);
         while(bytesRead > 0) {
             baos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
             bytesRead = responseData.read(buffer);
         }
         baos.close();
         connection.close();

         result = new String(baos.toByteArray(), "UTF-8");
         System.out.println("JSON RECIBIDO --> " + result);

     } catch (IOException ex) {
        //screen.requestFailed(ex.toString());
         System.out.println("FALLÓ:: " + ex);

     } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();        
     }        
}
```